# Create text file from bash script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm playing around with a simpler way to make animated GIFs with captions using [gifify](https://github.com/TSCBennett/gifify/blob/master/gifify.sh) (forked from [jclem](https://github.com/jclem/gifify)) using `ffmpeg` and it's captioning library. I tried adding a variable to my script, looking for the optional argument, but I can't even get it to create the temporary `.srt` file necessary.

Here's my script creating a `.txt` as proof of concept:

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts "t" opt; do
    case opt in
        t) text=$OPTARG;;
    esac
done

shift $(( OPTIND - 1 ))

subtitles=$1

#If there is text present, do this
if [ -z ${text} ]; then
    #Make an empty txt file
    cat >> /tmp/subs.txt
    text=$subtitles
    append ${text}
fi
```

I then run it with:

`sh text.sh -t "This is my text"`

The script runs and will echo out the string of text you put into the shell, but it won't add it to the new file. Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What does `append` do in bash?

Comment: That script should stop and wait for input when it gets to the `cat` line. That should be `cat /dev/null > /tmp/subs.txt`.

Comment: You only showed what the script does when `$text` is empty. What does it do when you supply this argument, as in the example?

Comment: `[ -z $variable ]` is an unsafe test. If `$variable` is empty that test will still pass because the shell will end up seeing `[ -z ]` which `[` will then interpret as `[ -n -z ]` and pass as `-z` is non-empty. The test needs to be `[ -z "$variable" ]` to force an empty variable to be an empty string.

Comment: Nothing in that script creates a `.srt` file. So it isn't surprising that one isn't created.

Comment: I knew I was creating a `.txt`, this was just to work out the bigger process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## !/bin/bash

1) You need `case $opt`.

```
while getopts "t:" opt; do
    case $opt in
        t) text=$OPTARG;;
    esac
done

shift $(( OPTIND - 1 ))

subtitles=$1
```

Then,

```
if [ -z "$text" ]; then #safer and just as long as the curly bracket version
    #Make an empty txt file
    : > /tmp/subs.txt #This is how you create an empty file
    cat /dev/null > /tmp/subs.txt #A longer version of the same thing
    #cat >> /tmp/subs.txt #This APPENDS standard input (STDIN) to /tmp/subs.txt
    text="$subtitles"
    #append ${text} #`append` isn't bash
    echo "$subtitles" > /tmp/subs.txt #the .txt file will contain what's in $subtitles

fi
```

Edit: 
@Etan Reisner makes a good point about the quotation marks.

1) You don't need them in `text=$subtitles`; bash handles this OK
2) You don't need them in your case in `echo $subtitles` either--echo works OK with multiple arguments, which is what a bare $subtitles expands to--but you'd better off putting them there too, to make it work for cases like:

```
a='-e hello\nworld'
echo "$a" #Without the qutoes, $a would get expanded and `-e` would get treated as a flag to `echo`
```

I thinks it's a good practice to quote variables in bash defensively and not rely on quirks like that in the assignment in 1) or echo's not distinguishing between `echo hello world` and `echo "hello world"`.

Comment: Quote `"$subtitles"` in the `echo`. Quotes not needed in the `text=$subtitles` assignment line.

Comment: I'm running into one more weird problem. The `-t` flag is pulling the filename, not the text after the flag. Advice?

Comment: `while getopts "t:"` -- you need a colon there to specify that -t requires an argument. Sorry about not catching that one. I'm not really well familiar with getopts and I sort of assumed you'd done your research on how to use it.

Comment: I'm learning as I go. I thought I had researched enough, and the colon was a problem, but didn't solve the problem I'm having. Thanks for helping out so much already.

Answer (score 0):

The question is little unclear but here I believe your basic problem is how to create or append a file. Here is the way to create a new file or append it in a shell script. Hopefully this will help. You can use it the way you want ->

Creating a file ->

```
cat<<EOF>/tmp/subs.txt
${text}
EOF
```

OR

```
echo "${text}" >/tmp/subs.txt
```

Appending a file (note extra '>') ->

```
cat<<EOF>>/tmp/subs.txt
${text}
EOF
```

OR

```
echo "${text}" >>/tmp/subs.txt
```

The EOF sometimes doesn't work  due to tab or white spaces if you dont keep your text left-aligned.

Also regarding "text=$subtitles"; you cannot do that operation after 'cat' so move it before 'cat' command.